# Node.js module.exports coding design patterns

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Following is two ways that can be used to declare a node.js module.

**Approach 1**

```
function foo() {
  //do something
}

module.exports = foo;
```

**Approach 2**

```
module.exports = (function(){
  function foo(){
    //do something
  }

  return foo;
})();
```

Out of these two, what is the best way to declare a module? and why. Is there any performance differences in both of them?

Thank you.

Comment: for me approach one is good.. easy to read and less number of lines

Comment: there is more than 2 approach, just pick whatever suit your module best, or look at some popular module on github to see what they use.

Comment: Approach 2 is strange. Just use `module.exports = function(){ /* do something */ };` instead.

Comment: @str : I was using the second approach. But when using JSdocs, it ignores doc comments inside the closures. So my documentation was empty. There are some tedious approaches to solve this, but I feel like moving from approach 2 to approach 1.